# Symbolic linking in Terminal (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: symbolic-link, osx-el-capitan, ln

I want to create symbolic links for all files in a folder `parent/target/`. I want the links to be in the folder `parent/destination/`. My working directory is `parent/` for the following terminal output using `bash`:

`$ cd target/

$ ll

total 16

drwxr-xr-x   4 jesse  staff  136 Feb 23 16:31 ./

drwxr-xr-x@ 10 jesse  staff  340 Feb 23 16:38 ../

-rw-r--r--   1 jesse  staff   10 Feb 23 16:23 file.txt

-rw-r--r--   1 jesse  staff   10 Feb 23 16:23 file2.txt

$ ln -s * ../destination/

$ ll ../destination/

total 16

drwxr-xr-x   4 jesse  staff  136 Feb 23 16:38 ./

drwxr-xr-x@ 10 jesse  staff  340 Feb 23 16:38 ../

lrwxr-xr-x   1 jesse  staff    8 Feb 23 16:38 file.txt@ -> file.txt

lrwxr-xr-x   1 jesse  staff    9 Feb 23 16:38 file2.txt@ -> file2.txt`

Why is it creating symlinks that link to themselves?? I have read the `ln` man page and various other `ln`-related SE questions, but I guess I am just missing something.

*(I am using bash in the Terminal in OS X 10.11.3)*

Comment: You need to specify an absolute path in the source, such as `ln -s /home/jesse/target/* ../destination/`.

Comment: @AFH Thanks. That worked perfectly. Why does `ln` require an absolute path for the target?? Are there other bash programs which require absolute paths? This isn't something I've come across before. Also, please add that as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute path in the source: in your case it would be:

```
ln -s $PWD/* ../destination/
```

Unlike a hard link, where the directory entry created directly references the same source file, a symbolic link holds the text of the original file reference. Indeed, the source file need not exist when a symbolic link is created, though obviously your use of `*` ensures that only existing source files are used.

In fact it's a little more complicated than that: if you specify an absolute path in the link, then referencing the link acts as if you had specified the original file; but if you specify a relative path, this is added to the directory where the link resides. So an alternative you could use from the `target` directory is:

```
cd ../destination/; ln -s ../target/* .
```

This would have the same effect as an absolute path, but has one distinction: if the whole directory tree were copied or moved to another location (eg somewhere in a different user's directory), the links will reference the files in their new location. The choice of absolute or relative links will therefore depend on whether you would ever wish to copy or move the source files together with the links: if the source files will always remain in the same location, use absolute links.

Comment: This definitely answered my question and taught me a few things. Thanks for that. I do have a question about the last bit... I tested what you suggested about using a relative path to see if the links would follow the moved files, but they didn't. My structure looks like `/a/1.txt /a/2.txt /aa/ /b/` and I ran `cd b/; ln -s ../a/* ./` which produced the links, but then when I moved the two text files to folder `aa`, the links no longer worked.

Comment: I don't think you quite understood what I said about relative links: you need to move both the original files and the links as part of the same subdirectory structure; you can't move one and not the other. So, if your files are `dir1/a/*.txt` and the links are `dir1/b/*.txt`, then you can move/copy the entire `dir1/` structure to `dir2/` and the links will still work, whereas absolute links would still reference `dir1/`; if you move the files independently of the links, you will need to remake the links - in your case to `../aa/*`.

Comment: Ok, that clears it up for me. Thanks for all the info.